# How to cancel the timer on java?

Tags: java, timer

How can I Cancel the timer when `i2 == 690`.

This is my code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer = new Timer(false);
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (i2 == 690) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        i2--;
        System.out.println("Java " + i2);
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: what is the initial values of i2?

Comment: And what happens when you run this code?

Comment: Do you want to cancel just that current task or all tasks being executed by the Timer?

Comment: This is not matter i just want the timer cancel when i2 is equal to 690

Comment: It's ok i got what i need thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call [TimerTask.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel--). So just call this.cancel() in the run() method there, instead of on timer (as `this` will refer to the anonymous class instance that the run method belongs to).

If you need to cancel other tasks executed by the timer, Timer.cancel() will stop those as well (what you are currently doing), but does not stop the current executing TimerTask which is why the above cancel on the TimerTask is needed.

[To quote from the Javadocs of Timer.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel--)

> Does not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists).

...

> Note that calling this method from within the run method of a timer task that was invoked by this timer absolutely guarantees that the ongoing task execution is the last task execution that will ever be performed by this timer.

So combining both cancels should do the trick of canceling the entire Timer if that is what you need.

Comment: That will only cancel the `TimerTask`. The timer will continue to run and any other scheduled tasks will continue to execute.

Comment: @MikeB I thought that's what he wanted. I'll ask him in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (i2 == 690) {
timer.cancel();
timer.purge(); 
return;
}
```

[Timer#cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel())-Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks.Does not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists)

[Timer#purge()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#purge()) - Removes all cancelled tasks from this timer's task queue.

Answer (score 0):

You should cancel timerTask, if you want to cancel executing process timerTask.cancel(), but if you cancel all process after executing process timer.cancel();